# Network mount /var with systemd

Tags: rhel, mount, systemd, encryption

I'm trying to get my system to mount `/var` with a custom script that downloads the decryption key from a network server. I had a solution that worked in RHEL 6 with SysVinit. I'm trying to port that to RHEL 7 with systemd.

I need `/var` to be mounted early in the boot process before other services that write to `/var` are started. It's tricky because I have `Requires=network-online.target` and `After=network-online.target` dependencies.

I have a working `encryption-mount@var.service` file that downloads the decryption key and mounts `/var`. It works if I run it in isolation, but not during bootup.

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount encrypted partition %f
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=download-key@dev-sdb1.service
After=download-key@dev-sdb1.service
Before=remote-fs.target
After=remote-fs-pre.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/my-custom-mount-script %f

[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
```

With this, it looks like the download-and-mount process is being kicked off early in bootup, but the system isn't waiting for it to complete. Everything continues booting in parallel causing all sorts of services to fail because `/var` isn't writable.

(By the way, I can't get around having to use custom scripting. I would love to use the built-in encrypted FS mechanisms, but for accreditation reasons beyond my control I cannot.)

Comment: Answerers should be aware of the February 2016 discussion by systemd developers on the subject of mounting `/var`.

Comment: systemd-devel mailing list, beginning with a message ("_the chopping block_") by Lennart Poettering on 2016-02-11

Comment: For anyone coming across this later, here's a link to the discussion: https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2016-February/035749.html